# AWS Credential provided by Identity Pool is invalid

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to consume some resources on **AWS** using **Cognito User Pool** authentication, after integrating it with **Identity Poll** and associating a role to it, I am getting AWS credentials, but when I try to use it, I am getting the following error message: `An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.` Any clues how to identify the issue? I am sharing part of my code below, I believe I am. missing some configuration.

[image: .NET code]

Comment: Where's the code for `GetCallerIdentity`? If it's what I think it is, you're trying to get an IAM identity for a Cognito token...

Comment: How do you know that the AWS credentials given to you is incorrect

Comment: @ArunK to test credentials I have tried it using .NET SDK's trying to access some resource that I know is associated with role I created, another test I did, I run `aws sts get-caller-identity` on console after running `aws configure` with those credentials.

Comment: @ps2goat please, check the answer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assume a role (which is what happens when you use Cognito), the credentials returned include an `AccessKeyId`, `SecretAccessKey` and `SessionToken` (sometimes referred to as `SecurityToken`). You need to use all 3 when authenticating against the AWS apis.

Comment: I don't use .NET but the docs on how to use temporary credentials with the sdks is located here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html#using-temp-creds-sdk You'd have to check the .NET SDK docs for the specific implementation